# Writing json objects to file

Tags: json, go, io

There is such workflow of writing `json` objects to file :

```
for {
    Step 1. create json object
    Step 2. Save object to file
}
```

So I wrote such code

```
f, _ := os.Create("output.json")
defer f.Close()
a1 := A{Name:"John", Surname:"Black"}
a2 := A{Name:"Mary", Surname:"Brown"}

a1_json, _ := json.MarshalIndent(a1, "", "\t")
a2_json, _ := json.MarshalIndent(a2, "", "\t")
f.Write(a1_json)
f.Write(a2_json)
```

As a result I have:

```
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Surname": "Black"
}{
    "Name": "Mary",
    "Surname": "Brown"
}
```

Which is not correct `json` file, because it doesn't have opening and closing braces and comma like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Surname": "Black"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Mary",
    "Surname": "Brown"
  }
]
```

How can I write to file in an appropriate way?

Comment: @Volker Maybe there are some `go` libraries which can handle such cases?

Comment: Then SO is the wrong place to look for such. But honestly: writing a , to a file doesn't require a dedicated package. The overhead to import something like this is bigger than just writing the ,.

Answer (score 3):

Just make a slice of the structures and save it. This will create the JSON array.

```
f, _ := os.Create("output.json")
defer f.Close()
as := []A{
    {Name:"John", Surname:"Black"},
    {Name:"Mary", Surname:"Brown"},
}
as_json, _ := json.MarshalIndent(as, "", "\t")
f.Write(as_json)
```

If you really want you can separate the elements manually.

```
f, _ := os.Create("output.json")
defer f.Close()
a1 := A{Name:"John", Surname:"Black"}
a2 := A{Name:"Mary", Surname:"Brown"}

f.Write([]byte("[\n"))
a1_json, _ := json.MarshalIndent(a1, "", "\t")
f.Write([]byte(",\n"))
a2_json, _ := json.MarshalIndent(a2, "", "\t")
f.Write([]byte("]\n"))

f.Write(a1_json)
f.Write(a2_json)
```

You can also consider using [JSON Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming) which can achieve your goals but the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: it breaks a workflow, because I want to get an `json` object and then store it to file in a loop.

Comment: if that is the case, you would need to write each one in different file

Comment: This is the correct way of using the Go's JSON library. If you want, you can add the brackets and commas yourself to the stream but you do it at your own risk. It is not hard to do it but it will not stand a code review.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich I added a not on JSON Streaming, you may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Put those structs into a slice and marshall the slice instead

```
f, err := os.Create("output.json")
if err != nil{
   panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()
a1 := A{Name:"John", Surname:"Black"}
a2 := A{Name:"Mary", Surname:"Brown"}

a := []A{a1, a2}
a_json, err := json.MarshalIndent(a, "", "\t")
if err != nil{
   panic(err)
}
f.Write(a_json)
```

Also, always check for `err` wherever possible